# Hex string passed to php script in $_REQUEST array isn't being interpreted?

Tags: php, web, passthru

Here's a really simple example:

```
$val = "";

if(array_key_exists("param", $_REQUEST)) {
    $val = $_REQUEST["param"];
}

print "echo \"$val\"";
passthru("echo \"$val\"");
```

I'm expecting the `passthru()` to print `A` if I pass `test.php?param=\x41`. However, it doesn't look like PHP is interpreting the escape sequence and passing "\x41" to `passthru`. I know that the `\xAA` shorthand only works on double quoted strings in PHP, but that condition should be satisfied in the example above. Does reading a variable out of `$_REQUEST` modify anything?

Comment: Escape sequences are only processed in string literals, not string data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape sequences aren't expanded in strings, they're only expanded in string *literals* in code.

The shell command `printf` will process escape sequences in its format string argument, so you can do:

```
passthru("printf '$val'");
```

You can also use a shell string quoted with `$''` to process escape sequences.

```
passthru("echo \$'$val'");
```